# Which one is faster? Two fors inside of an if-else statement or a single for statement with an if-else statement?

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I don't know if that forum is the right place for doing such a question but here it is:

Which one should I use for more optimization? A single `for` statement with an if-else statement or two `for` statement inside of an `if-else`?
For example, supposing that items is a huge `list`:

```
    void doSomething(List items, boolean test)
    {
        for(item : items) {
            if (test) {
               // do A statements
            } else {
               // do B statements
            }
        }
    }
```

And the second example:

```
    void doSomething(List items, boolean test)
    {
        if (test) {
           for (item : items) {
               // do A statements
           }
        } else {
            for (item : items) {
               // do B statements
            }       
        }
    }
```

So, I know that the second example may look like a code duplication, but the point is, as we can see on the first example, the computer is going to make the same tests over and over for each item of the list, is it really a problem for optimization? Since inside the loop, the test boolean is not going to change its value at all.

Comment: If the compiler implements the code as written, then the second version is better. If the compiler is smart (and is optimizing for speed, not size) then it may generate the same code for both.

Comment: you'll need to benchmark (or disassemble) to see exactly what your compiler does

Comment: This is known as loop unswitching, pretty basic optimization

Comment: Simply try it yourself. Profile which is faster.

Comment: In modern compilers, the first example will effectively be re-structured to match the second, so there should be negligible difference, if any at all.

Comment: Pro-tip.  Make the name of a boolean variable be a yes/no question which its value is the answer to.  This simple change will greatly reduce how many times you accidentally reverse its meaning, making for a hard to spot bug.  That kind of coding discipline is far more important than micro-optimizing performance in this way.

Comment: @btilly: this is a toy program, don't you think ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, and if you have good habits, you automatically do them without thinking.  Even on toy programs.  For example the code is indented properly.  Naming booleans as questions can be just as automatic. `isTest` instead of `test`.

Comment: You're probably trying to optimise prematurely / unnecessarily, but this minor performance difference is particularly important, you need to benchmark it. If you're not asking about a specific language, this is even more true.

Comment: @btilly: this is just as if you were telling the OP "`doSomething` is a poor name for a function." BTW, `isTest` is quite inappropriate, you don't check if something is a test or not.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Would `isTestMode` be preferable to you?  And I disagree with you.  My point is that habits around maintainability are more important than micro-optimizations.  I believe that accepting this value statement is important and worthwhile in the development of a junior programmer.

Comment: @btilly: IMO this is not the place to pass your message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would prefer the second construct as it avoids the repetition of the test.

As claimed by others, the compiler might do the transformation. But you don't know for sure, and the cost of duplicating the loop statement isn't significant.